# HttpClient doesn't return in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webclient

Simple enough, here's my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Fetches the JSON string from the URL.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">URL to download the JSON from.</param>
/// <returns>JSON formatted string</returns>
private static string GetJsonResponse(string url)
{
    var result = DownloadString(url).Result;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Downloaded from {0} with result = {1}", url, result);
    return result;
}

private static async Task<string> DownloadString(string feedUrl)
{
    var result = "";
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Downloading from {0}", feedUrl);
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        result = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(feedUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
        result.Trim();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Finished download from {0}", feedUrl);
    }
    return result;
}
```

it prints the first string but there's no way to get to second one, and this means that the `client.GetStringAsync` doesn't return.

The URL is ok, it loads fine.

What's my problem?

EDIT 2:
(Removed as useless now)

EDIT 3:

I'm adding the methods that I'm using to let you know what's the flow of my data.

Page.xaml

```
<phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1" x:Name="UpcomingResultsList" ItemsSource="{Binding UpcomingMovies}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MovieListDataTemplate}" Margin="0, 10, 0, 0" />
```

`UpcomingMovies` is bound to this property

```
public List<MovieViewModel> UpcomingMovies
    {
        get
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UpcomingMovies - Begin");             
            var apiMovies = _serviceRT.FindUpcomingMoviesList().Result; // We get the movies in RT API's format
            var movies = apiMovies.Select(result => new MovieViewModel(result)).ToList();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UpcomingMovies - End");
            return movies;
        }
}
```

the `_serviceRT.FindUpcomingMoviesList()` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a list of upcoming movies.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>MovieSearchResults</returns>
public async Task<MovieSearchResults> FindUpcomingMoviesList()
{
    var url = string.Format(LIST_UPCOMING, ApiKey);
    var jsonResponse = await GetJsonResponse(url);
    var results = Parser.ParseMovieSearchResults(jsonResponse);
    return results;
}
```

Finally, the `GetJsonResponse()` is at the beginning of the question.

Now, having the full data flow, how can I bind this property and still make the download complete?

Comment: In testing, your code works perfectly fine. Additional information may be needed to resolve the issue here. For instance, any exceptions you may have received, the size of the text content being downloaded, whether or not your emulator actually has internet access correctly configured, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I predict that further up in your call stack, you are calling `Wait` or `Result` on a `Task` returned from an `async` method. [This can easily cause deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), as I describe on my blog.

This happens because `await` will by default capture a "context" which it uses to resume the `async` method. In your example, this is most likely a UI context, which always has exactly one thread (the UI thread). So if you block the UI thread by calling `Wait` or `Result`, then the `async` method cannot re-enter the UI context to complete its execution (and you end up waiting for a `Task` that cannot complete).

**Edit:**

Since you're databinding, I recommend using the `NotifyTaskCompletion` type [here](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20%28NET4,%20Win8,%20SL4,%20WP75%29/NotifyTaskCompletion.cs) (which will soon be part of my AsyncEx library):

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    UpcomingMovies = NotifyTaskCompletion.Create(LoadUpcomingMoviesAsync());
}

public INotifyTaskCompletion<List<MovieViewModel>> UpcomingMovies { get; private set; }

private async Task<List<MovieViewModel>> LoadUpcomingMoviesAsync()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UpcomingMovies - Begin");             
    var apiMovies = await _serviceRT.FindUpcomingMoviesList();
    var movies = apiMovies.Select(result => new MovieViewModel(result)).ToList();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("UpcomingMovies - End");
    return movies;
}
```

Then you can safely bind to `INotifyTaskCompletion<T>.Result` like this:

```
{Binding UpcomingMovies.Result}
```

Note that until you load the movies, the result will be `null` so your view will be empty. Also, if there is an error loading the movies, your view will always be empty. I recommend that you handle these situations by databinding to the other `INotifyTaskCompletion<T>` properties, e.g.:

- `{Binding UpcomingMovies.IsCompleted}`, which will start out `false` and become `true` when the loading completes (either successfully or in error)
- `{Binding UpcomingMovies.IsSuccessfullyCompleted}`, which becomes `true` only if/when the loading completes successfully
- `{Binding UpcomingMovies.IsFaulted}`, which becomes `true` only if/when the loading completes with an error
- `{Binding UpcomingMovies.ErrorMessage}`, which extracts the error message (and is `null` if there is no error)

Comment: I think that you gotthe point. I'm calling the method (not directl though) in a button click handler just to test some stuff with the API. Do you think that moving the call in the `Model` (I'm using MVVM pattern) will make it work right? If not, how can I fix it? (Please note that I'm already using something like the second solution in your block, I'm adding the full code to the question!)

Comment: The best way to fix it is to use "async all the way". Replace every `Wait` or `Result` with `await` and iterate from there. Your `GetJsonResponse` and `GetJSON` should end up being `async`, which you can `await` from an `async` `Loaded` handler (or use the [`async` initialization pattern](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) for your VMs that I describe on my blog).

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it. I'll try to give you some other info. This code is in a library with no UI (just a plain c# library) that contains the classes to match the JSON response of the API that I'm using. This library contains a method called `GetMovie(int id)` which gets the JSON and parses it into a `Movie` object to be used in another project's `Model` class. To do this, it calls the `GetJsonResponse(string url)` in the question. Does making everything `async` mean that even the `GetMovie` has to return something like `Task<Movie>` ?

Comment: @StepTNT: Yes; it has to be `async` "all the way".

Comment: Well, I did as you said by changing each metod to be `async` but now I need to read the data in a property bound to a XAML control and so I need to access the `Result` object. And this means that everthing gets stuck again.

Comment: I recommend using my `NotifyTaskCompletion` type that [I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html).

Comment: I know that you're really putting your efforts into this but I still don't undertsand how to make it work. I've read your blog article but I don't get how to adapt your last solution to my case. I've edited the question giving the full data flow of my methods' calls so that you can easily understand what I'm actually doing.

Comment: Your solution works for 2/3 of my `PivotItem`. Each one needs to load and display the same kind of data and using the same `ItemTemplate` but one of them loads it starting from a `Command` bound to a `Button`. So, the two that load that in the constructor are working, while the one that uses the `Command` loads fine but it doesn't show anything. Any idea?

Comment: If you're setting a property outside of a constructor, be sure to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient has limitations according to platform it is called from (like other network-related APIs on Windows Phone if compared with "big windows"). Maybe, this how-to will help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/02/18/portable-httpclient-for-net-framework-and-windows-phone.aspx

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, resourceAddress);
request.Content = streamContent;
if (handler.SupportsTransferEncodingChunked())
{
    request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
}
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```